# Chrome glitch and Hover event

Tags: css, google-chrome

i have a weird problem with Chrome only. I have a menu on my website with a submenu that shows only when parent item get hovered. 
Here's my CSS :

```
.menu .liFirstLevel ul  
{  
  position: relative;  
  background-image: url(/imgs/bg-submenu.jpg);  
  background-repeat: repeat; 
}

.menu .liFirstLevel:hover ul {  

  display: block;  
  z-index: 5;  
  padding: 0px;    
  line-height: 30px;
```

}

Here's the problem : Lets supppose that i have a parent menu with a submenu that contains 3 options. Like this :

```
    <ul class='menu'>
        <li class='liFirstLevel'>
            <ul class='submenu'>
                <li>SubMenu1</li>
                <li>SubMenu2</li>
                <li>SubMenu3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

When i hover the ul.menu, the submenu always display, as supposed to. But when i try to select one of the subitem menu, it disapear as soon as the crusor is at the middle height of the first subitem... So in the exemple above, As soon as i reach the middle height of "Submenu1" my submenu disapear. Now here's the strange part : If i minimize chrome and then bring it back, the bug is gone...
My menu is 100% functionnal. So i'm pretty sure my CSS is ok...

Any ideas of what i can try ? I tried so many things.
I hope i'm clear, it's a bit complex to explain !

Thanks

Comment: well this style `.menu .liFirstLevel:hover .ul` is wrong. It should be `.menu .liFirstLevel:hover ul` (change `.ul` to `ul`)

Comment: Hi Zgood, yeah my bad, i made the mistake when i wrote my code to explain the problem. The real css file is as you mentioned -> ul (not .ul)